# Exposed Service and Replica Set Relation in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have a question about how kubernetes decides the serving pod when there are several replicas of the pod.

For Instance, let's assume I have a web application running on a k8s cluster as multiple pod replicas and they are exposed by a service.

When a client sends a request it goes to service and kube-proxy. But where and when does kubernetes make a decision about which pod should serve the request?

I want to know the internals of kubernetes for this matter. Can we control this? Can we decide which pod should serve based on client requests and custom conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we decide which pod should serve based on client requests and custom conditions?

As kube-proxy works on **L4** load balancing stuff thus you can control the session based on  **Client IP**.  it does not  read the header of client request.

you can control the session with the following field **service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig** in **service obejct**

following command provide the explanation 
`kubectl explain service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig`

Following paragraph and link provide detail answer.

> Client-IP based session affinity can be selected by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to “ClientIP” (the default is “None”), and you can set the max session sticky time by setting the field service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds if you have already set service.spec.sessionAffinity to “ClientIP” (the default is “10800”)[-service-proxies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)

Service object would be like this

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10000
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh ! Also, when there is no service running and I create two independent Pods running the same application. Is there anything similar to AffinityConfig there?

Comment: Service object provide stability to the pods, as the podIP can be changed in its lifecycle as its a immutable object.   two independent pods are not replica of each other.

Comment: Also, you need to have a service object in order to expose it internally or externally

Comment: Yes, sure services are more flexible and convenient. But can we do above settings at Pod level?

Comment: I did not find anything related to session affinities in the podspec, you can also verify with the following command `kubectl explain pod.spec --recursive | grep -i affinity`

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes service creates a load balancer(and an endpoint for it) and will use round robin by default to distribute requests among pods.

You can alter this behaviour.
As Suresh said you can also use sessionAffinity to ensure that requests for a particular session value always go to the same pod.